# hibernate session to use specific jdbc connection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I have legacy application.Legacy application first begin the transaction  through its core logic. where it associates
the jdbcConnection in pool. It does not use any hibernate here. This is Step 1

Then it opens the session with `sessionFactory.openSession();` This is step 2

what i am not getting is how connection in step1 got associated with hibernate session in step2. Does hibernate provides
this kind of configuration any how?

Guys i can not paste code associated with above classes as its huge.

Comment: it probably uses 2 different connections, as hibernate will open its own connection when it calls `openSession()`. Alternatively, the app might be configured with a datasource that somehow returns the same connection that the other parts of the code use (maybe some kind thread aware connection?). Anyway, following Occam's razor principle, it probably uses 2 different connections.

Comment: You cannot, hibernate manages its connections by itself (well, via connection pools to be exact, built in or external) You would have to implement your own connection pool, whitch is not worth of time i think.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide custom connection with below in hibernate configuration file

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">yours Custom connection provider class</property>
```